# VBA: chkbox_click event triggered by changing value chkbox

Tags: vba

I have a userform which is dynamically filled by checkboxes. To improve usability I've added a checkbox "Select all" which either selects or deselects all checkboxes. This works perfectly. Now I want the "Select all" checkbox to be unchecked (value=False) automatically once one of the other checkboxes is unchecked.

In order to achieve this I've created a class module. This class module also does what it's supposed to. But, and here's my problem, once the value of "Select all" is changed, the "Select all" checkbox_click event is triggered, which means all other checkboxes are being unchecked as well, and that's obviously not what I want! I've already tried to use the MouseDown and MouseUp events instead, but these events behave irregular and often lead to the wrong results.

**Question:** How do I stop the Click event from running everytime the value of this checkbox is changed without the checkbox actually being clicked?

Here's my code:

```
Private colTickBoxes As Collection
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim ChkBoxes As cls_RIRI
Dim ctrl As Control

'Controls are created on run time here
'Some events to change the height of the userform and the top value of several buttons

    'Make sure click events work
    Set colTickBoxes = New Collection

    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" And Left(ctrl.Name, 1) = "M" Then
            Set ChkBoxes = New cls_RIRI
            ChkBoxes.AssignClicks ctrl
            colTickBoxes.Add ChkBoxes
        End If
    Next ctrl

Set ctrlCHK = Nothing
Set ChkBoxes = Nothing
Set ctrl = Nothing

End Sub
```

And the class module:

```
Private WithEvents chkBox As MSForms.CheckBox
Public Sub AssignClicks(ctrl As Control)

    Set chkBox = ctrl

End Sub
Private Sub chkBox_Click()

    If chkBox.value = False Then UserForms(0).Controls("chkSelAll").value = False

End Sub
```

And the chkSelAll_Click sub:

```
Private Sub chkSelAll_Click()

Dim ctrl As Control

    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" And Left(ctrl.Name, 1) = "M" Then
            If chkSelAll.value = True Then
                ctrl.value = True
            Else
                ctrl.value = False
            End If
        End If
    Next

Set ctrl = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: How are you setting the selectall checkbox to be checked, is it clicking chkSelAll?  This would be clicked to select all, and un-checked once another checkbox is selected.

Comment: Yes, clicking the chkSelAll changes the values of the other checkboxes to true or false. I've edited the original message with the Sub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a public variable, say blnBypassNonUIClick and set this, then when coming from the UI, by a human click set it to false, and when setting the select all the same.  Your select all, shouldnt activate click if you're setting the .value by code.  Something like this....

```
Public blnNonUI As Boolean

Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    If Not blnNonUI Then
        MsgBox "hello"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()
    blnNonUI = True
    Me.CheckBox1.Value = 1
    blnNonUI = False
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a splendit idea! I can make this work! Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Nathan_Sav gave me this idea and it works:

```
Public blnHumanClick As Boolean

Private Sub chkSelAll_Click()

If blnHumanClick = True Then

    Dim ctrl As Control

        For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
            If TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" And Left(ctrl.Name, 1) = "M" Then
                If chkSelAll.value = True Then
                    ctrl.value = True
                Else
                    ctrl.value = False
                End If
            End If
        Next

    Set ctrl = Nothing

    blnHumanClick = False

End If

End Sub

Private Sub chkSelAll_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

    blnHumanClick = True

End Sub
```